# AngularJS - templating with sub-routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to Angular.js and I can't seem to figure out how to solve my problem.

**The app** consists of three main tabs which are also top-level routes, ie.

```
#/home
#/inbox
#/products
```

The current route-configuration looks something like this (coffeescript):

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/home', templateUrl: 'home.html').
  when('/inbox', templateUrl: 'inbox.html').
  when('/inbox/:thread_id', templateUrl: 'inbox.html', controller: 'MessagesCtrl').
  otherwise(redirectTo: '/inbox')
```

Now, the **problem is the inbox view**.

The inbox view (`inbox.html`) is a split column template with a list of message-threads to the left and the messages of the selected thread to the right:

```
 --------------------------
| Navigation               |
 --------------------------
|         |                |
| Threads |    Messages    |
|         |                |
|         |                |
```

The list of threads should be visible for all `#/inbox` routes no matter if a thread has been selected or not.

As you can see from the routes, the inbox view is a separate template (`inbox.html`) which is loaded both when a thread is selected and when it's not. This makes Angular re-render the entire view each time a thread is selected, which also causes the thread-list (to the right) to re-render and loose its scroll-position.

I would like to keep the thread-list from re-render whenever a thread is selected and I can't seem to figure out how to organize my routes/templates in order to achieve this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried to add [reloadOnSearch=false] parameter to your route definition object where you dont whant reload?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't help. To my understanding, $location.search() only refers to the query-string-part of the URL (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. However, I was able to solve it using this technique:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm
https://github.com/bennadel/AngularJS-Routing

It's was bit more complicated to implement, but for my case I think it is worth it in the end

Comment: It's 1 1/2 year later, and I found the best solution to be UI-Router, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router. (This is after reading through Ben Nadel's article and its comments and studying the various solutions suggested there.)

Answer (score 5):

Please check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/778), I believe your problem is exactly the same.

If you change the URL path, everything inside the `ng-view` will be re-rendered and there's no way to avoid that. However, if you set the `reloadOnSearch` to *false* on the route configuration and then use links like `/inbox?id=1`, the `ng-view` will not be re-rendered. This is probably the best solution for your problem, you can use deep linking and avoid re-renders.

Regarding the `reloadOnSearch` property, angularjs [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) states:

> [reloadOnSearch=true] - {boolean=} - reload route when only
>   $location.search() changes.
>
> If the option is set to false and url in the browser changes, then
>   $routeUpdate event is broadcasted on the root scope.

You just need to listen for the `$routeUpdate` event to update the information inside the inbox controller, like this:

```
app.controller('InboxCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {      
    $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(value) {
        // update the model/$scope here based on the $routeParams info...
    });    
});
```

**jsFiddle** example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/ZB56n/